# Is the variation in the spelling of the agent-noun suffix -er/-or related to any phonetic difference?

Tags: pronunciation, agent-noun-suffix

[This excerpt](https://i.imgur.com/w2gWvw2.jpg) in a book on English suffixes piqued my interest. Is there any phonetic correlate between the way the nouns below are pronounced and their spelling? I know *execut-or*/*-er* admits two stress patterns, but perhaps there are others as well. Since all these spelling conventions seem to vary somewhat between dialects and speakers I was wondering if it was the cause or effect of a difference in speech.

> abstractor (= -er), connector (= -er), constructor (= -er), contradictor (+ -er), detector (= -er), detractor (= -er), impactor (= -er), obstructor (= -er), protector (= -er), selector (= -er) tormentor (= -er), adjustor (= -er), protestor (= -er), executor (= -er)

Comment: How could there ever be any phonetic differences? Those are unstressed syllables, which means they're reduced to schwa in both cases. Schwa is as schwa does.

Answer (score 0):

A conclusion on the basis of this short list is obtained from the SOED (*The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*); it can be summarized as follows.

In most cases the suffix is "*-or*" (exceptions: "abstracter, adjuster") and the variant in "*-er*" does not exist (or must be extremely rare) or is rare. In rare cases (1) both suffixes are in use ("*protester, protestor*")  In rare cases only (2)  is there a difference in meaning.

The suffixes "*-or*" and "*-er*" are not stress imposing and therefore stress is preserved in all cases, except as concerns "*executor*", where the pronunciation \ɪg 'zek jʊt ə\ (main form) is an exception to be contrasted to \'eks ɪ kju:t ə\, a pronunciation  reserved for the less important word "executor" as meaning "performer"  (stress according to the usual stress assignment as required by the suffix).

***Difference***

- **abstracter** a person who abstracts; a person who makes an abstract or abstraction.
  **abstractor** an abstracter; *spec.* (now *Hist.*) as a title or a grade of clerks in the British Civil Service.
- **connecter** see CONNECTOR
  **connector**  Also (esp. of a person) **-er**

***No difference***

- **constructer** obsolete
  **constructor**
- **contradicter** (*does not exist*¹ (user LPH))
  **constructor**
- **detecter**  see DETECTOR
  **detector** Also (now *rare*) **-er**
- **detracter**  see DETRACTOR
  **detractor** Also (now *rare*) **-er**
- **impacter** (*does not exist* (user LPH))
  **impactor**
- **obstructer** (*does not exist* (user LPH))
  **obstructor**
- **protecter** (*does not exist* (user LPH))
  **protector**
- **selecter** (*does not exist* (user LPH))
  **selector**
- **tormenter** (*does not exist* (user LPH))
  **tormentor**
- **adjuster**
  **adjustor** (*does not exist* (user LPH))
- **executer** see EXECUTOR
  **executor**
- **protester**   (*more important form, [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=protester%2C+protestor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)*)²
  **protestor** = PROTESTER

¹  <sub>i.e. does nor appear as an entry in the SOED</sub> 
²  <sub>not in the SOED, added information</sub>